# ASP NET Core MVC delete row and local file at the same time using Url.Action in <a>

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I tried to delete a row by selecting in table in my FileManager View image, but it doesn't work. Nothing happens. Are my HttpGet and HttpPost functions was wrote correctly? Maybe I missed something?
Moreover, I need to delete local file in /wwwroot/storage. How can I do it with deleting a row at the same time? Thank you.

**Delete func in my WorkSpaceController**

```
private readonly TextCloudContext Context;
[HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Delete(int UserId)
    {
        Models.File file = Context.Files.SingleOrDefault(f => f.Id == UserId);
        return RedirectToAction("FileManager");
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Delete(string Id)
    {
        int CurrentId = Int32.Parse(Id);
        Models.File file = Context.Files.Single(f => f.Id == CurrentId);
        Context.Files.Remove(file);
        Context.SaveChanges();     
        return RedirectToAction("FileManager");
    }
```

**FileManager view**

```
<table class="table" style="text-align: center">
<tr>
    <th>
        @Html.ActionLink("File Name", "FileManager", new { sortingOrder = ViewBag.SortingName, Filter_Value = ViewBag.FilterValue })
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.ActionLink("File Type", "FileManager", new { sortingOrder = ViewBag.SortingExtension, Filter_Value = ViewBag.FilterValue })
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.ActionLink("Date", "FileManager", new { sortingOrder = ViewBag.SortingDate, Filter_Value = ViewBag.FilterValue })
    </th>
    <th>
        <a>Actions</a>
    </th>
    <th></th>
</tr>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Extension)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Date)
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="@Url.Action("Download", "WorkSpace", new { Name = item.Data })" class="">
                <img style="width: 25px;" src="~/Media/MenuIcons/download.png" title="Download"/>
            </a>
            <a href="@Url.Action("Delete", "WorkSpace", new { UserId = item.Id })">
                <img style="width: 25px;" src="~/Media/MenuIcons/delete.png" title="Delete" 
                     onclick="return confirm('Delete this file?')"/>
            </a>
        </td>
    </tr>

}
```

**TextCloudContext.cs**

```
public class TextCloudContext : IdentityDbContext<TextCloudUser>
{
    public TextCloudContext(DbContextOptions<TextCloudContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }
    
    public DbSet<File> Files { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    }
```

**File.cs with get and set values for DbSet in context**

```
public class File
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "File Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Data { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Type")]
    public string Extension { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Date")]
    public string Date { get; set; }

    public string UserID { get; set; }

    public TextCloudUser User { get; set; }
}
```

**FileViewModel as a model of FIles table from DbSet comm in context (created by using a migration)**

```
public int Id { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "FileName")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "File")]
    public IFormFile Data { get; set; }
    public string Extension { get; set; }
    public string Date { get; set; }
    public string UserID { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your Delete action has the could which should delete the record from the database but not the code that deletes a file from the file system. To delete a file from file system, you need to call [System.IO.File.Delete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.delete?view=netcore-3.1) method.

Your second problem is that your delete button is a link, so clicking it will issue a GET request which will match the first Delete method (marked with `[HttpGet]` attribute).

In order to have it issue a POST request you need a form and a submit button.

```
<form asp-action="Delete" asp-controller="Workspace" asp-route-Id='item.Id' method="post">
   <button type="submit" onclick="return confirm('Delete this file?')">
       <img style="width: 25px;" src="~/Media/MenuIcons/delete.png" title="Delete" />
   </button>
</form>
```

Note I am using the TagHelpers here which is preferred to the `@Url.Action` way you were doing.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need post method.your action link requests GET method.

Here is an example on how your get method should look like:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Delete(int fileId)
    {
        Models.File file = Context.Files.FirstOrDefault(f => f.Id == fileId);
        if(file != null)
        {
             Context.Files.Remove(file);
             Context.SaveChanges();
             if(IO.File.Exists(AbsolutePath of the file)
             {
                   IO.File.Delete(AbsolutePath of the file);
             }
         }
        return RedirectToAction("FileManager");
    }
```

Comment: Exists method isn't work, because it's inappropriate in this context...

Comment: I have updated my answer as it was confusing to use which File class needed and where. To check if a file exists or to delete a file you need IO.File and I have also changed the parameter to fileId make sure you are passing the same from your mvc view